# how to decode URL-encoding character (string and array) in php?

Tags: php, urldecode

I want to fix this issue:

[image: this is a select list]

this is a list of my wordpress category but it language is Persian and show like this!

I've convert all php files into UTF8 encoding but didn't work.

how can fix?

Answer (score 0):

ha ha :) I've find solution.

Just decode the URL format with this function:    `urlencode ( string )`

but my issue is not string it is array with changing count.

I fixed with this code:

```
$count=count($blog_categories);
for ($x=0;$x<$count;$x++){
$blog_categories[$x] = urldecode($blog_categories[$x]);}
```

comment: `$blog_categories` is my array. this array returns category in wordpress.

and result:

[image]

I hope My experience can help you someday!

good luck :)